# Remove, filter or hide JSON response data?

Tags: php, json

Every user has a `.txt` file named as his `username`
for example: `john.txt` has IDs in rows like this

```
12345
12222
13541
35165
```

IDs are updated after postback fires.
Now, this is an example of JSON response:

```
"offers":[{"offerid":21982,"name":"Norton WiFi Privacy VPN - (iPhone, INCENT Free, US, 42M)","name.....
```

I'm displaying data

```
foreach($json['offers'] as $offer) {
```

Using `echo`

How do I filter out or remove 'offers' that maches with the IDs from txt file ?

Comment: Could you store the id's from the "jhon.txt" file in array?

Comment: Well I could, but it would destroy my database. I choose txt with a reason, there will be thousands of users, and per user 100's of IDs.

Comment: A solution provided by Okneloper below :)

Answer (score 1):

[file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) is a function that will load a text file into an array.

You can do something like this:

```
<?php
$ids = array_map('trim', file("./john.txt"));
foreach($json['offers'] as $offer) {
    if (in_array($offer['offerid'], $ids)) {
        // skipping
        continue;
    }
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm.

Comment: One more question, could this work with XML tho ? foreach($xml->campDetails as $detail){          Gonna try.